# Memorize quotes python program

Tags: python

I want to create a program where i can either memorize all quotes of a book or from certain characters. Once the type of test is selected, I want to enter a quote I can remember and if it is present in a file then I can continue to enter more quotes. Once finished, a score is presented. To be honest this is all I've done already - i need a bit of help with All_AIC.

```
def displayMenu():
    print('Inspector Calls quotes:')
    print('1. All AIC quotes')
    print('2. Arthur quotes')
    print('3. Sheila quotes')
    print('4. Inspector quotes')
    print('5. Eric quotes')
    print('6. Gerald quotes')
    # INPUT menu item
    i = input('Please select an option from the menu above(1-6):')
    # VALIDATION of menu item
    while not (i.isnumeric() and int(i)>=1 and int(i)<=6):
        i = input('Error - Please select an option from the menu above(1-3):')
    return i # RETURN menu item

while True:
    choice = displayMenu()
    if choice=='1':
        all_AIC()
    elif choice=='2':
        arthur()
    elif choice=='3':
        sheila()
    elif choice=='4':
        inspector()
    elif choice=='5':
        eric()
    elif choice=='6':
        gerald()
    else:
        print('Wrong choice - enter valid number')

def all_AIC(): # Def means defigning a function
    print('Write your quotes, press # to finish')
    quotes = input('Quotes:') #INPUT username
    quotes = quotes.lower()
    quotefile = open('all_AIC.txt', 'r')
    quotelist = quotefile.readlines()
    quotefile.close()
    found = False
    for line in quotelist:
        if str(quotes) in line:
            print(line)
            found = True

    if not found:
        print('Quote not found')
        quotefile.close()
```

Comment: Is `quotes` supposed to consist of multiple quotes? `input` allows you to read only one line. Aside from this, the terribly inefficient searching algorithm and the fact that you close an already closed file, I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: So your All_AIC is a function to ingest a quote and return a message with the same quote if the quote is found, or with the string 'Quote not found'? The approach is valid, I think you'd be frustrated by any mispelling or punctuation, so you may want to use regex to remove punctuation or replace common misspellings like 'teh' or any other habits you yourself have when you type.